# Checking for delayed asynchronous code in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

A little ticky question, First, I have a plugin:

```
exports.action = function(){
  // Running synchronous code
  runMyRequest("path/to/url", function(){
    // My code is asynchronous
  });
}
```

Then I call this plugin from a require:

```
var plugin = require('myplugin')
plugin.action();
// continue stuff
```

**Question:** Is there any ways at "continue stuff" to check if "My code is asynchronous" is running or finished ? And so wait for it ?

**Note:** In my real code plugins must call a callback(). The purpose of this question is to do something if plugin's code forget to call my callback()

Comment: I was thinking of a Join() feature like in Java or C#.

Comment: You're not understanding closures. If the callback is not called, "My code is asynchronous" is never run. The question is not whether "it is running" or "it is finished", it's never run. There is no "threads" exposed in node (and V8), so there is no join() possible. Node allows the programmer to halt or crash the server. It is not designed to cope with sloppy code. The only workaround, based on timeout, is the one provided by djbrick.

Comment: @Lucio Yes, I was talking Join() for better understanding. I was thinking of ugly while/timeout loop looking at Event Loop to see if there is activity for this module

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe so but you can use `setTimeout` to call a function if the plugin doesn't call the callback in a specific period of time. If the callback is called you clear the timeout.

Comment: Yes it's a kind of workaround. I was thinking of a Join() feature like in Java or C# or a low level NodeJS feature to track function call.

Answer (score -1):

> > Question: ... And so wait for it ?

I've recently created a simple abstraction named WaitFor to call async functions in sync mode (based on Fibers): https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

First, "action" should have a callback as parameter, because as it is written in your example, it is an async function (returns immediately) but it doesn't have a callback.

your code with wait.for:

```
exports.action = function(callback){
  // Running synchronous code
  runMyRequest("path/to/url", function(){
    // My code is asynchronous
    ...
    callback(err,data);
  });
}
```

Then call this plugin from a require:

```
var wait = require('wait.for')
var plugin = require('myplugin')

...in a fiber...
wait.for(plugin.action); // waits until callback is called (WITHOUT BLOCKING NODE)
// continue stuff
```

Wait.for will give you other advantages, like sequential try-catch programming, when needed.

Comment: As I said the real code do have a callback but I want to check when plugins do not call callback(err,data);